# Gradle: building a fat war with jar dependencies

Tags: gradle, groovy, ant, ivy

I'm trying to migrate from Ant + Ivy to Gradle and am unable to properly include transitive dependencies.

For example, I have a following Ivy dependency:

`<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jdbc" rev="4.2.0.RELEASE"/>`

As Ivy report shows, this artifact depends on `spring-tx`, which is being retrieved by Ivy and placed to `WEB-INF/lib` as a jar. But Gradle does not do that by default and this code doesn't do the trick either (it just doesn't put any `spring-tx` related `.class` files in there):

```
from { configurations.compileClasspath
            .findAll { !it.name.endsWith('pom') }
            .collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } {
        into('WEB-INF/classes')
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can include transitive dependencies as jars and put them in `WEB-INF\lib`?

Comment: do you use the Gradle `war` plugin ?

Comment: yes, i do use this plugin

Comment: `war` plugin is exactly what you need I think. see my answer below: please try this very simple project setup and check if you get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle `war` plugin can be used for that (see [War Plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html)).

Below is a very simple example of `build.gradle` script that will create a `war` with all needed dependencies (and transitives dependencies) under `/WEB-INF/lib`

```
plugins{
    id "war"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{    
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.2.0.RELEASE'

}
```

The `war` produced with `./gradlew build` will contain all the `spring-jdbc` libraries and its dependencies ( `spring-beans` ,   `spring-core`,  `spring-tx` ...) in */WEB-INF/lib*  folder.

Comment: i do use this plugin, it does not place any transitive dependencies into `WEB-INF/lib`, only the declared ones

Comment: did you try the simple 9-lines script above? I see no reason that you don't get transitive dependencies fetched.. btw, which Gradle version are you using?